# Add User to database that is on server canot be found

Tags: sql-server, permissions, sql-server-express

I have a SQL Server Express instance, 2 databases on the server 3 and 4.

Server 4 has [IIS APPPOOL.NET v4.5] as a user

I want to add [IIS APPPOOL.NET v4.5] as a user to Server 3.

Cannot get Database properties screen see or accept [IIS APPPOOL.NET v4.5]

[image]

Comment: How do you know that user exists?

Comment: Why is the \ needed just before the period?  [IIS APPPOOL\.NET v4.5]

Comment: @charlieface User exists on the same instance for another database on same server

Comment: @BartMcEndree Cut and paste of user from db in same server & instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used DB tree to add the user.

[image]